# How does IF and MOD function work to calculate time elapsed in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel-formula

I am not able to get to know how the IF function or the MOD function is calculating the time elapsed. Syntax is okay but how it is working is not clear

Comment: Please add more context to this post. What are you trying to calculate? What have you tried and what was wrong with it?

Comment: You need to post a [mre] including your function. `IF` and `MOD` on their own have nothing specific to do with time, but `MOD` is useful to parse time if you need to split a decimal quantity of _hours, minutes or seconds_ into 12 or 24 hour time notation. Show use you specific context and the answer will be provided.

Comment: My question is built into your answer.. How MOD parses time? The function is returning the time elapsed per se but how I am not able to figure out

Comment: "Syntax is ok" what syntax? (Post the formula). Also, if you're asking us how it works, how do you judge it's ok?